# Option Explicit and Macros in a function

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code:

```
    Option Explicit

Public Function LastWeekOfMonth() As Boolean

'finds the current date
    Dim CurrentDate As Date
    CurrentDate = CDate(ActiveSheet.Cells(FIRST_DATA_ROW, 1))

'find filepath and filename
    Dim filepath As String
    Dim filename As String

    filepath = "C:\target\file\path\here\"
    filename = Cells(3, 4) & ".m_d.xlsm"
    MsgBox (filepath & filename)

     'if it is the last week of the month, write a monthly report, and return true to continue with the face to face paperwork
     If (31 - Day(CurrentDate)) <= 7 Then
        'write a monthly report
        Dim app As New Excel.Application
        Dim wsheet As New Worksheet
        Dim book As Excel.Workbook

        app.Visible = False 'Visible is False by default, so this isn't necessary
        Set book = app.Workbooks.Open(filepath & filename)
        Set wsheet = book.Worksheets("Monthly")

        'Application.Run ("WriteMonthly")
        app.book.wsheet.Run ("WriteMonthly")
        book.Close SaveChanges:=True
        app.Quit
        Set app = Nothing
        LastWeekOfMonth = True

    'if it is not, simply continue with the face to face paperwork
     Else
        LastWeekOfMonth = False
     End If

End Function
```

WriteMonthly is a macro that is currently contained in the target spreadsheet. Documentation online says that macros can be run through application.run(macro name, arg1,arg2,arg3, ...)

I want to pull information from the current spreadsheet to call up a specific spreadsheet and run a macro on that spreadsheet, with the code for that macro being on that spreadsheet, and eventually any data that is generated to be stored on that spreadsheet.

This is part of a form which looks at if the last days of the month have been reached; if they have, write a specific "monthly" report.

The problem is this:

```
app.book.wsheet.Run ("WriteMonthly")
```

doesn't work and neither does:

```
Application.run("!WriteMonthly")
```

Comment: Try adding the worksheet name before the macro name. You had the `!WriteMonthly` but add the workbook name first.  If that doesn't work, then perhaps you need the whole path too.

Comment: If your 'filename' doesn't contain spaces, try: Application.Run "C:\path\...\Book1.xls!WriteMonthly"

Comment: @sous2817 yes it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is `Application.Run "'WbkName'!ProcedureName"`

However because the procedure you are calling resides in an Object Module (a worksheet in this case) the syntax has to include the name of the object as well, such as this: `Application.Run "'WbkName'!ObjectName.ProcedureName"`

`Application.Run "'" & filename & "'!ObjectName.WriteMonthly"`

Replace `ObjectName` with the name of the `VbModule` of the worksheet `Monthly`.

Try: `Application.Run "'" & filename & "'!" & wsheet.CodeName & ".WriteMonthly"`

Also ensure that procedure `WriteMonthly` is **not declared as `Private`** in the `Monthly' Module

Comment: hi I am using the following:         Application.Run "'" & filepath & filename & "'!" & wsheet.Name & ".WriteMonthly" which says that it is not available. The I want to run the sub WriteMonthly which is located in module WriteMonthly on worksheet Monthly in the target workbook.

Comment: gets error 1004

Comment: thanks it works! final syntax:        Application.Run "'" & filepath & filename & "'!" & "WriteReport" & ".WriteMonthly"